# Semantic-based recommender Facebook application

Tags: facebook, semantic-analysis

As a project of this semester my friend and I are thinking to make a semantic-based recommender Facebook application. For example, if I wanted to go "a trip to Europe", this application is intended to do the following: go search in my friends list and gives me back all photos albums having the name "Italy Travel" or even only containing a comment about "Eiffel Tower", my friends statuses related to anything in Europe, notes of my friends, links they have liked in other websites and other activities that show up in their news feed. And same goes if I want to watch a movie, read a book or study a subject...etc.

And my question is:

1. Is such thing possible to be
   achieved within 3 months? knowing
   that we have only the very basis
   about Facebook API and semantic
   related subjects.
2. If it is, what Ontology can we rely
   on? And what other concepts should
   we have as a starting block?

Comment: The Facebook API part is answered. As for semantic processing and ontology issues, any ideas where to start from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 3 Months Most probably yes (depends upon how much you already know about Facebook API).

Things you should know before embarking on journey to develop this (Some i think are significant enough..)

- Either you can go about developing whole Interaction Code between your server and Graph API yourself.
- Or use some SDK that are already out there.(Some are mentioned in Facebook docs) Like [Facebook C# SDK for C#](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation).
- Understanding of FQL and Graph API (Make some small project first to try and test things like getting user friend list).
- Basic understanding of HTTP GET and POST requests and how to construct them in language of your choice.
- Parsing JSON in your language.
- Get a print out of documentation of selected topics for offline reference (*I did that...*)

Comment: So, I'll put it that way: The project include two main parts:
1-dealing with Facebook API.

Comment: yup :)... Dealing can be handeled by either your custom code or an SDk then you can do semantic processing on data  recived..